# "Unsource" a .bash_profile or .bashrc script

Tags: bash

I had a function in my ~/.bash_profile file, like so:

```
function foo {
  echo "foo"
}
```

after sourcing the .bash_profile file,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I can run foo at the command line:

```
$ foo
```

say I want to change the name of foo to bar

```
function bar {
  echo "foo"
}
```

and I re-source the .bash_profile file

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It appears that both `foo` and `bar` are available at the command line. Why is that? and how can I clear the old .bash_profile code out of memory or wherever it's being stored?

Answer (score 2):

the `source` command just merges the results of the executed file with the current environment. There's no reverting back to the previous state.

After such a change, most people close all existing windows and open new ones: problem solved;

But, you could delete all functions before sourcing your command (not only the ones contained in the sourced file, but *all* of them, which is maybe a bit overkill) like this:

```
unset `declare -F | cut -f3 -d" "`
```

(`declare -F` lists the functions, just get their names and pass them to `unset`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to unset foo

```
unset -f foo
```

By sourcing your bash profile you are essentially just 'adding' more information you aren't creating a fresh shell.